# Where can I download best raw files

Tags: photoshop

I am new to photoshop  and need images to practice. I  searched in google for raw files, but with little success .Most of the images are having less resolutions.  I have got very few best images from adobe.  Where can I download the raw files, images which are unedited with good resolution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get free RAW files online for practicing with Lightroom?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25413/where-can-i-get-free-raw-files-online-for-practicing-with-lightroom)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to take your own pictures or ask a friend for some. Most digital SLR cameras shoot raw pictures. Some P/S cameras do that as well. Any answer to this question is going to be based on a personal opinion.