# Is there a comparison resource supplying RAW photos for download?

Tags: raw, comparison

I'd like to compare some digital cameras for purchase.

All of the online reviews I can find offer JPEG samples (which means the RAW data has been filtered and modified according to the settings on the camera). This doesn't help with an accurate comparison.

Is there a comparison resource which supplies RAW file downloads for review?

Comment: Realize that the best raw converters for many cameras are the ones supplied by that camera's manufacturer and not the ones included in third party software such as Lr, DxO, etc. So to know the true potential of the raw files from any particular camera you would need to compare them using the manufacturer's raw converters.

Comment: Not a duplicate because you want ones for specific camera models, but certainly related: [Where can I get free RAW files online for practicing with Lightroom?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/25413/1772)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dpreview.com has RAWs from all the cameras it reviews available for download. [Example](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/image-comparison/fullscreen?attr18=daylight&attr13_0=sony_a7_ii&attr13_1=sony_a7&attr13_2=nikon_d610&attr13_3=canon_eos6d&attr15_0=raw&attr15_1=raw&attr15_2=raw&attr15_3=raw&attr16_0=200&attr16_1=200&attr16_2=200&attr16_3=200&normalization=full&widget=1&x=0&y=0)